# No frameworks detected in IntelliJ IDE when trying to import a project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have to add/change some features in a Spring boot api which has a blueprint repository. I downloaded the branch from gitlab and opened the same in IntelliJ. But IntelliJ does not detect any framework. Even the basic spring imports are failing. Also I usually use Maven as build tool, but the project requires me to use Gradle, However I am not allowed to download gradle on their environment(even my local). Can anyone please point me in the right directions please.

Comment: How did you import the project in intellij-idea ?

Comment: Right-click the project and choose `Add Framework Support` (mostly at the top of the menu) and choose Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to build the project from the command prompt:

```
gradlew clean build
```

If this is building successfully you are good to use the project in IntelliJ as a normal Java project and add/edit code. If this is not working then check what's the issue and update the question.

To add framework support (in your case Gradle as you mentioned) right-click the project and choose `Add Framework Support` (mostly at the top of the menu) and choose Gradle.

**Edit**

After successful `gradlew clean build`, reimport the project in IntelliJ by selecting `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I went for a clean build and solved some problems related to it. However the problem seems to be in the Framework support, my company restricts the import of unapproved frameworks, I believe I will have to take a look at that and ask someone if there are some approved packages I could use.

Comment: @Tusharj it is not clear when you say some problems are solved when you did a clean build. If Gradle is not installed and it is a Gradle based project it won't even build. If the `gradlew clean build` successfully ran in your command prompt it means Gradle is already available in your system. Now, coming to IntelliJ, try creating a new project/module and observe at the left-hand panel what all options you see. Do you see Gradle, Maven, etc. here? Secondly, I am assuming you have a `build.gradle` file in your project. Try re-importing the project by selecting `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @fiveeelements 
re-importing the project by selecting build.gradle file is the solution. Getting a clean build after re-import solved all configuration problems.

Comment: @Tusharj glad that it worked. Now you can start working on your project module in IntelliJ. I have updated the answer accordingly.  Would you please accept the answer?